# Reusing view/view controllers?

Tags: ios, view, controllers

I have a view and its view controller. They get the job done and work as I want to. One of the functionalities is when the user taps the view, something gets added to it.

I'm adding new features to my app and I could reuse my view and its view controller BUT when the user taps on the view, I don't want anything to be added. What could be a good approach? Should I configure my controller depending on who is calling it? This then implies that I need to check throughout my code how my view and view controller are being used (ex: if (isAllowedToAdd) {...} )

This feels messy and I think I'm missing the point of MVC. Any suggestions?

Comment: I was hoping someone would answer this. I have the same question. It feels messy to me to have to add flags in my controller, etc. But it also doesn't feel right having multiple controllers doing almost the exact same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think it depends on the "something" that gets added to your view.
Maybe a good compromise would be to separate all common code/functionalities in a parent class from which each controller would inherit?

You can also set a custom init method that would take a parameter defining whether add is allowed or not. Then just enable/disable the whole tap gesture recognizer (I guess you have one) based on this parameter. Thus, you would not have to check any flag throughout your code.